# Logstash output is from another input

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, pipeline, metricbeat

I have an issue where my beatmetric is caught by my http pipeline.

Both Logstash, Elastic and Metricbeat is running in Kubernetes.

My beatmetric is setup to send to Logstash on port 5044 and log to a file in /tmp. This works fine. But whenever I create a pipeline with an `http` input, this seems to *also* catch beatmetric inputs and send them to `index2` in Elastic as defined in the `http` pipeline.

Why does it behave like this?

**/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/http.conf**

```
input {
  http {
    port => "8080"
  }
}

output {

  #stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {

    hosts => ["http://my-host.com:9200"]
    index => "test2"
  }
}
```

**/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/beats.conf**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

output {
    file {
        path => '/tmp/beats.log'
        codec => "json"
    }
}
```

**/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml**

```
pipeline.id: main
pipeline.workers: 1
pipeline.batch.size: 125
pipeline.batch.delay: 50
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
http.port: 9600
config.reload.automatic: true
config.reload.interval: 3s
```

**/usr/share/logstash/config/pipeline.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline"
```

Comment: how are you starting logstash? are you using multiple pipelines with pipelines.yml configuration?

Comment: Updated my question. Basically the pipeline.yml is pointing to a pipeline directory with both conf files. Everything is running in Kubernetes (and thus are started automatically via the docker image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have multiple config files, they are read as a single pipeline by logstash, concatenating the inputs, filters and outputs, if you need to run then as separate pipelines you have two options.

Change your `pipelines.yml` and create differents `pipeline.id`, each one pointing to one of the config files.

```
- pipeline.id: beats
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/beats.conf"
- pipeline.id: http
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/http.conf"
```

Or you can use `tags` in your `input`, `filter` and `output`, for example:

```
input {
  http {
    port => "8080"
    tags => ["http"]
  }
  beats {
    port => "5044"
    tags => ["beats"]
  }
}
output {
 if "http" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://my-host.com:9200"]
        index => "test2"
      }
  }
 if "beats" in [tags] {
      file {
        path => '/tmp/beats.log'
        codec => "json"
      }
  }
}
```

Using the `pipelines.yml` file is the recommended way to running [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.7/multiple-pipelines.html)

Comment: Make sense. This was the missing piece for me. Thanks!